# Error: Unsupported class file major version 62

Tags: android, kotlin, compiler-errors, android-jetpack-compose

I have been getting this error for a project. It used to run without any problem but for some reason it stopped working and this error started to show up. Not sure why it happens so will post it here in case it happens to someone as well. Anyone know why this error keeps on happening?

Error Log: This is what is shown in the build output.

```
Cause: java/text/SimpleDateFormat
```

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 62
    at com.android.tools.tracer.agent.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:196)
    at com.android.tools.tracer.agent.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:177)
    at com.android.tools.tracer.agent.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:163)
    at com.android.tools.tracer.agent.TraceTransformer.transform(TraceTransformer.java:46)
    at java.instrument/java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer.transform(ClassFileTransformer.java:244)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:541)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.System$2.defineClass(System.java:2342)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyBuilder.defineProxyClass(Proxy.java:560)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyBuilder.build(Proxy.java:670)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy.lambda$getProxyConstructor$0(Proxy.java:429)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.AbstractClassLoaderValue$Memoizer.get(AbstractClassLoaderValue.java:329)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.AbstractClassLoaderValue.computeIfAbsent(AbstractClassLoaderValue.java:205)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyConstructor(Proxy.java:427)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:1037)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser$1.run(AnnotationParser.java:302)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser$1.run(AnnotationParser.java:300)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.annotationForMap(AnnotationParser.java:300)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:289)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:121)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:73)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.declaredAnnotations(Field.java:1265)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.declaredAnnotations(Field.java:1263)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.getAnnotation(Field.java:1230)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getFieldNames(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:74)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:161)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:489)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:962)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:901)
    at com.android.tools.analytics.AnalyticsSettings.loadSettingsData(AnalyticsSettings.kt:268)
    at com.android.tools.analytics.AnalyticsSettings.initialize(AnalyticsSettings.kt:345)
    at com.android.build.gradle.options.ProjectOptions.<init>(ProjectOptions.java:61)
    at com.android.build.gradle.options.ProjectOptionService.<init>(ProjectOptionService.kt:53)
    at com.android.build.gradle.options.ProjectOptionService$Inject.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:483)
    at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.AsmBackedClassGenerator$InvokeConstructorStrategy.newInstance(AsmBackedClassGenerator.java:2070)
    at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.AbstractClassGenerator$GeneratedClassImpl$GeneratedConstructorImpl.newInstance(AbstractClassGenerator.java:488)
    at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.DependencyInjectingInstantiator.doCreate(DependencyInjectingInstantiator.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.DependencyInjectingInstantiator.newInstance(DependencyInjectingInstantiator.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.services.internal.BuildServiceProvider.calculateOwnValue(BuildServiceProvider.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.get(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:84)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.BasePlugin.basePluginApply(BasePlugin.java:327)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.BasePlugin.lambda$apply$0(BasePlugin.java:313)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.crash.CrashReporting.runAction(crash_reporting.kt:27)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.BasePlugin.apply(BasePlugin.java:311)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.BasePlugin.apply(BasePlugin.java:157)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ImperativeOnlyPluginTarget.applyImperative(ImperativeOnlyPluginTarget.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.RuleBasedPluginTarget.applyImperative(RuleBasedPluginTarget.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.addPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:187)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.access$100(DefaultPluginManager.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager$AddPluginBuildOperation.run(DefaultPluginManager.java:282)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.lambda$doApply$0(DefaultPluginManager.java:167)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:166)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.apply(DefaultPluginManager.java:146)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyType(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:167)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:98)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:190)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPluginAware.java:49)
    at com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.apply(AppPlugin.kt:28)
    at com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.apply(AppPlugin.kt:24)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ImperativeOnlyPluginTarget.applyImperative(ImperativeOnlyPluginTarget.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.RuleBasedPluginTarget.applyImperative(RuleBasedPluginTarget.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.addPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:187)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.access$100(DefaultPluginManager.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager$AddPluginBuildOperation.run(DefaultPluginManager.java:282)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.lambda$doApply$0(DefaultPluginManager.java:167)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:166)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.apply(DefaultPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.lambda$applyPlugin$1(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:128)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugin(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:184)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugin(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:126)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.access$200(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:60)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator$1$1.lambda$add$1(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:107)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.lambda$applyPlugins$0(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:122)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:122)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:117)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.lambda$apply$0(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:44)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:366)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:393)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:365)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:35)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.lambda$run$0(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:366)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$withProjectLock$3(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:426)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:211)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withProjectLock(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:426)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:407)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:365)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:751)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:151)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.ensureConfigured(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:339)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:41)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:57)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(DefaultProjectsPreparer.java:48)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.java:64)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer$ConfigureBuild.run(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:40)
    at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.lambda$prepareProjects$1(VintageBuildModelController.java:93)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$1(StateTransitionController.java:222)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:243)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:221)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.StateTransitionController.transitionIfNotPreviously(StateTransitionController.java:190)
    at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.prepareProjects(VintageBuildModelController.java:93)
    at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.doBuildStages(VintageBuildModelController.java:77)
    at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.prepareToScheduleTasks(VintageBuildModelController.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$prepareToScheduleTasks$0(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:105)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$1(StateTransitionController.java:222)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:243)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:221)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.StateTransitionController.maybeTransition(StateTransitionController.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.prepareToScheduleTasks(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:103)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.scheduleRequestedTasks(DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$doScheduleAndRunTasks$2(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:86)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.withNewTaskGraph(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:94)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.doScheduleAndRunTasks(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:85)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$runBuild$4(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:103)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$0(StateTransitionController.java:145)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:243)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.StateTransitionController.transition(StateTransitionController.java:145)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.runBuild(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:100)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.scheduleAndRunTasks(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:66)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.run(ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:69)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:114)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:155)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:211)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:103)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:69)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the Java Version on Gradle Setting. Change Java 1.8 to Java 11

File -> Setting ->Build,Execution,Deployment

[image]